# Disable Lock Screen

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to replace the stock lock screen (with an app, not a rom).
What is the best way to do it, for a start to disable the lock screen on as much devices as possible?
Thanks!

Comment: You can read a discussion about this here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f66dfab6c300eb6f/f9bc83e8eef1e2d4?pli=1

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

in androidmanifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Comment: The class KeyguardLock has been deprecated.  Setting the window flags as shown by @hsgubert below seems the current way to turn off the key guard/lock screen.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Have been looking for this from last 3 days :)

Answer (score 33):

You can just use this line in the activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Comment: I also added this to the top of the main activity:

   `import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;`

Comment: This didn't work for me, maybe you have to also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>` to the manuifest

Comment: no, this didn't work for me

Comment: This worked instead: `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
`

Answer (score 7):

Try this, it will keep awake the screen/ display , as long as the activity is on top.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Also this does not require any permission in manifest.

Comment: Instead of writing same answer, you could have upvoted the answer by @hsgubert

Comment: @CopsOnRoad. Solution seems to be different than that is provided by hsgubert. 
Is it something I am missing here ?

Comment: I also added this to the top of the main activity: `import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;`

Answer (score 2):

Check  out this link http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

listen to the screen on intent and I guess just launch your lock screen.

Comment: can u pls elaborate your answer @Faisal Abid