# cancel the events of lock/unlock on my android application

Tags: android, onresume, unlock

When i unlock my device to see my application, the process in `onResume()` is launched. How do I cancel the events of unlock, to avoid `onResume()` from processing?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. Why would you want to change this?

Comment: I guess you can set the timer for auto lock in settings, if I have understood your question properly.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701928/disable-lock-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent unlock your device use below flag in your activity.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
```

**Code**

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

**Note :**

As stated on the Activity lifecycle docs, onCreate and onResume will always both be called the first time an Activity is started. When going back to Activity, at least onResume will be called

Answer (score 1):

`OnResume` is always called when your Activity was in background (e.g. other App, Lockscreen, Homescreen... is shown). 
Look at the [Activity Life Cycle](http://techstub.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/activity_lifecycle.png) to check if you can move your code from `onResume()` maybe to `onStart()` to fix your issue.