# When is lock screen re-enabled

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

My app needs to remove the lock screen of Android devices. It is done as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095866/2618890) and it works.

When does the lock screen come back? For example suppose I write those lines of code in my main activity and the user starts my app, until when the lock screen will not appear?

Answer (score 0):

Until a call to the `reenableKeyguard()` method of your `KeyguardLock` object.

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard(); //keyguard disabled
//some code
lock.reenableKeyguard(); //keyguard reenabled
```

(Also I suppose a restart would re-enable it too. ;])

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html#disableKeyguard()

Comment: I suppose it would be relinquished. Test it! =]