# Show heads up notification only if current activity is in fullscreen mode?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am building a VoIP app and it has an incoming call screen. Instead showing the screen, I want to just show a heads up notification, if current foreground app is in full screen mode. Is this possible? Is there a way to check if the current running activity is in full screen?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365177/full-screen-notification-only-showing-as-a-heads-up

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        if(lp.flags == WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN){
            //Do your stuff
        }
```

**Edit**
If the running app is not your app you need to take a different approach which possible only from API 11, and use [View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html):

> Callback to be invoked when the status bar changes visibility. This reports **global** changes to the system UI state, **not what the application is requesting**

Comment: I want to check if the current foreground app (which is not mine) is in fullscreen mode or not.

Comment: @Codevalley hope this will help!